# Reading coordinates out of a string

Tags: c#, string, find

I want to read coordinates from a string that looks like this:

```
string coordinate = "20, 10   10, 20";

int x1 = 20;
int y1 = 10;
int x2 = 10;
int y2 = 20;
```

I want to store every number in a seperate integer variable.

It should not matter what numbers there are actually. So instead of `"20,10  10,20"` there could be **anything**... (`"x1,y1  x2,y2"`)

Comment: Are there always three spaces between the sets of coordinates? And how do you intend to assign the result to ints if it's something like `"john, paul    george, ringo"`?

Comment: How much control do you have over the formatting of the string?

Comment: there will never be a name or smthing like that. only numbers. and YES, there are always 3 spaces between the first and the second coordinate.

Comment: Do you care whether there's a space after the comma?

Comment: I already solved that problem.Thx anyways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` function:

```
string coordinate = "20, 10   10, 20";
var splitted = coordinate.Split(new[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         .ToList();
var x1 = splitted[0];
var y1 = splitted[1];
var x2 = splitted[2];
var y2 = splitted[3];
```

Comment: Instead of the `where` clause, you could use `Split(new [] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: @RobinBennett thank you very much for the great comment! Code has become cleaner, clearer  and shorter! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since fotmat is not clearly specified and some *unwanted* values like `"x1,y1"` can appear, I suggest *regular expressions* to match *valid* points, e.g.

**Code:**

```
  using System.Linq; 
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ....

  string coordinate = "20, 10   10, 20";

  Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<x>-?[0-9]+),\s*(?<y>-?[0-9]+)");

  var points = regex
    .Matches(coordinate)
    .Cast<Match>()
     // I've put Point but you may want different class / struct
    .Select(match => new Point(int.Parse(match.Groups["x"].Value), 
                               int.Parse(match.Groups["y"].Value)))
    .ToArray(); // Let's materialize into an array

  // int x1 = points[0].X;
  // int y1 = points[0].Y;
  // int x2 = points[1].X;
  // int y2 = points[1].Y;

  Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine, points);
```

**Outcome:**

```
{X=20, Y=10}
{X=10, Y=20}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\d+` will match every number in the string. Alternatively use `-?\d+` to match negative values as well.

```
string coordinate = "20, 10   10, 20";
var points = Regex.Matches(coordinate, @"\d+");
int x1 = int.Parse(points[0].Value);
int y1 = int.Parse(points[1].Value);
int x2 = int.Parse(points[2].Value);
int y2 = int.Parse(points[3].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse string to int array I'd use LINQ:

```
string coordinates = "20, 10   10, 20";
var points = coordinates
                       .Split(new[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Select(int.Parse)
                       .ToArray();
```

But you'd better off using class/struct or anonymous class to declare your Point:

```
    var pointsStrings = coordinates.Split(new[] {"   "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var points = pointsStrings
        .Select(ps => ps.Split(new[] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray())
        .Select(ps => new { X = ps[0], Y = ps[1]});

    foreach (var point in points)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"X = {point.X}, Y = {point.Y}");
    }
```